# Take Last VchNo and Group by Month and Sum Total Amount in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by, linq-to-entities

```
public partial class FeesVoucher
    {
        public long Auto_id { get; set; }
        public string VoucherNo { get; set; }
        public string StudentID { get; set; }
        public string SessionID { get; set; }
        public string ClassID { get; set; }
        public string SectionID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> IssueDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FeesDate { get; set; }
        public string FeeMonth { get; set; }
        public string FeeYear { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> RegistrationFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AdmissionFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SecurityDeposit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TutionFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Fine_Late_Fee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TransportCharges { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Lab_ExaminationFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AnnualCharges { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> BoardPECFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> OtherCharges { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public string FeesStatus { get; set; }
        public string PaidType { get; set; }
        public string CampusID { get; set; }
        public string FeesID { get; set; }
        public string VoucherMessages { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public string EditMsg { get; set; }
        public string IsEdit { get; set; }
        public string RevAcc { get; set; }
        public string RecAcc { get; set; }
    }

using (Entities db = new Entities())
                    {

                        var dt = (from stu in db.StudentsInfoes
                                  join CampusS in db.CampusSetups on stu.CampusID equals CampusS.CampusID
                                  join stuclass in db.StudentClassInfoes on stu.StudentID equals stuclass.StudentID
                                  join sectionID in db.ClassesSections on stuclass.ClassID equals sectionID.ClassID
                                  join classs in db.ClassSetups on stuclass.ClassID equals classs.ClassID
                                  join SessS in db.SessionsSetups on stuclass.SessionID equals SessS.SessionID
                                  join FeeV in db.FeesVouchers on stu.StudentID equals FeeV.StudentID 
                                  
                                  

                                  select new
                                  {

                                      StudentID = stu.StudentID,
                                      FullName = stu.FullName,
                                      FatherName = stu.FatherName,
                                      StStatus = stu.Status,
                                      ClassStatus = stuclass.Status,
                                      CampusID = CampusS.CampusID,
                                      RollNo = stuclass.RollNo,
                                      ClassID = stuclass.ClassID,
                                      ClassDesc = classs.ClassDesc,
                                      SectionID = sectionID.SectionID,
                                      SectionDesc = sectionID.SectionDesc,
                                      VoucherNo = FeeV.VoucherNo,
                                      SessionID = SessS.SessionID,
                                      Months = FeeV.FeeMonth,
                                      RegistrationFee = FeeV.RegistrationFee,
                                      AdmissionFee = FeeV.AdmissionFee,
                                      AnnualCharges = FeeV.AnnualCharges,
                                      SecurityDeposit = FeeV.SecurityDeposit,
                                      Fine_Late_Fee = FeeV.Fine_Late_Fee,
                                      BoardPECFee = FeeV.BoardPECFee,
                                      Lab_ExaminationFee = 
                                      FeeV.Lab_ExaminationFee,
                                      OtherCharges = FeeV.OtherCharges,
                                      TutionFee = FeeV.TutionFee,
                                      IssueDate = FeeV.IssueDate,
                                      DueDate = FeeV.DueDate,
                                      
                                      TotalAmount = FeeV.TotalAmount,
                                      FeeStatus = FeeV.FeesStatus,
                                      FeeYear = FeeV.FeeYear,
                                      FeesID = FeeV.FeesID,

                                  }

                              ).Where(x => x.FeeStatus.Equals("unpaid")).Select(x => new {x.VoucherNo,x.FullName,x.IssueDate,x.DueDate,x.Months,x.TotalAmount }).Distinct().ToList();
```

This query perfectly work without group and sum as shown in picture ===>
[Without Group and Sum Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKx2C.png)
after multiple tables joining this query build result like this

| VchNo | Student Name | Month | Total Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | aa | Jan | 2000 |
| 0002 | aa | Feb | 2000 |
| 0003 | aa | Mar | 2000 |
| 0004 | bb | Jan | 2000 |
| 0005 | bb | Feb | 2000 |
| 0006 | bb | Mar | 2000 |

But I want to modify my query to achieve group and sum as show in this picture ===>[With Group and Sum Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbhYO.png)
but I want to take last VchNo and group by month and sum total amount like this

| VchNo | Student Name | Month | Total Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0003 | aa | Jan,Feb,Mar | 6000 |
| 0006 | bb | Jan,Feb,Mar | 6000 |

what will be the query for entity framework 6.0
all answer will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("VchNo", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Student Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Total Amount", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001", "aa", "Jan", 2000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0002", "aa", "Feb", 2000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0003", "aa", "Mar", 2000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0004", "bb", "Jan", 2000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0005", "bb", "Feb", 2000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0006", "bb", "Mar", 2000 });

            DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Student Name")).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    group.Select(x => x.Field<string>("VchNo")).LastOrDefault(),
                    group.Key,
                    string.Join(",", group.Select(XmlReadMode => XmlReadMode.Field<string>("Month"))),
                    group.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Total Amount"))
                });
            }

        }
    }

}
```

---

Using Entity :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (Entities db = new Entities())
            {

                var dt = (from stu in db.StudentsInfoes
                          join CampusS in db.CampusSetups on stu.CampusID equals CampusS.CampusID
                          join stuclass in db.StudentClassInfoes on stu.StudentID equals stuclass.StudentID
                          join sectionID in db.ClassesSections on stuclass.ClassID equals sectionID.ClassID
                          join classs in db.ClassSetups on stuclass.ClassID equals classs.ClassID
                          join SessS in db.SessionsSetups on stuclass.SessionID equals SessS.SessionID
                          join FeeV in db.FeesVouchers on stu.StudentID equals FeeV.StudentID

                          select new
                          {

                              StudentID = stu.StudentID,
                              FullName = stu.FullName,
                              FatherName = stu.FatherName,
                              StStatus = stu.Status,
                              ClassStatus = stuclass.Status,
                              CampusID = CampusS.CampusID,
                              RollNo = stuclass.RollNo,
                              ClassID = stuclass.ClassID,
                              ClassDesc = classs.ClassDesc,
                              SectionID = sectionID.SectionID,
                              SectionDesc = sectionID.SectionDesc,
                              VoucherNo = FeeV.VoucherNo,
                              SessionID = SessS.SessionID,
                              Months = FeeV.FeeMonth,
                              RegistrationFee = FeeV.RegistrationFee,
                              AdmissionFee = FeeV.AdmissionFee,
                              AnnualCharges = FeeV.AnnualCharges,
                              SecurityDeposit = FeeV.SecurityDeposit,
                              Fine_Late_Fee = FeeV.Fine_Late_Fee,
                              BoardPECFee = FeeV.BoardPECFee,
                              Lab_ExaminationFee =
                              FeeV.Lab_ExaminationFee,
                              OtherCharges = FeeV.OtherCharges,
                              TutionFee = FeeV.TutionFee,
                              IssueDate = FeeV.IssueDate,
                              DueDate = FeeV.DueDate,

                              TotalAmount = FeeV.TotalAmount,
                              FeeStatus = FeeV.FeesStatus,
                              FeeYear = FeeV.FeeYear,
                              FeesID = FeeV.FeesID,

                          }

                      ).Where(x => x.FeeStatus.Equals("unpaid")).Select(x => new { x.VoucherNo, x.FullName, x.IssueDate, x.DueDate, x.Months, x.TotalAmount }).Distinct().ToList();

                var results = dt.GroupBy(x => x.FullName).Select(x => new
                {
                    VchNo = x.Last().VoucherNo,
                    Name = x.Key,
                    Months = string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Months)),
                    Amount = x.Sum(y => y.TotalAmount)

                }).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    public class Entities : IDisposable
    {
        public List<CampusSetups> CampusSetups { get; set; }
        public List<ClassSetups> ClassSetups { get; set; }
        public List<ClassesSections> ClassesSections { get; set; }
        public List<FeesVoucher> FeesVouchers { get; set; }
        public string SectionsSetups { get; set; }
        public List<StudentsInfoes> StudentsInfoes { get; set; }
        public List<StudentClassInfoes> StudentClassInfoes { get; set; }
        public List<SessionsSetups> SessionsSetups { get; set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
    public class ClassSetups
    {
        public string ClassID { get; set; }
        public string ClassDesc { get; set; }
    }
    public class ClassesSections
    {
        public string ClassID { get; set; }
        public string SectionDesc { get; set; }
        public string SectionID { get; set; }
    }
    public class SessionsSetups
    {
        public string SessionID { get; set; }
    }
    public class StudentClassInfoes
    {
        public string StudentID { get; set; }
        public string ClassID { get; set; }
        public string SessionID { get; set; }
        public string RollNo { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
    public class CampusSetups
    {
        public string CampusID { get; set; }
    }
    public class StudentsInfoes
    {
        public string CampusID { get; set; }
        public string StudentID { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class FeesVoucher
    {
        public long Auto_id { get; set; }
        public string VoucherNo { get; set; }
        public string StudentID { get; set; }
        public string SessionID { get; set; }
        public string ClassID { get; set; }
        public string SectionID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> IssueDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FeesDate { get; set; }
        public string FeeMonth { get; set; }
        public string FeeYear { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> RegistrationFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AdmissionFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SecurityDeposit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TutionFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Fine_Late_Fee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TransportCharges { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Lab_ExaminationFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AnnualCharges { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> BoardPECFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> OtherCharges { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public string FeesStatus { get; set; }
        public string PaidType { get; set; }
        public string CampusID { get; set; }
        public string FeesID { get; set; }
        public string VoucherMessages { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public string EditMsg { get; set; }
        public string IsEdit { get; set; }
        public string RevAcc { get; set; }
        public string RecAcc { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the custom data table. I want any suggestion for LINQ or entity framework context!

Comment: Linq is a query and isn't meant to add data to a datatable.  Code is easy to convert to Entity.

Comment: thanks, bro. question is updated. now can you suggest any better solution for me?

Comment: Does Distinct really work?  You need following for Distinct To work : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: Added Entity solution

Comment: Distinct is working. You can see in attachments pictures

Comment: Microsoft fixes things that didn't work in earlier versions of Net.  It is hard to keep track of the changes.  Distinct when you had mixtures of string and numbers would give errors.   Haven't try using distinct with mixtures in years.

Comment: Yes, it's work now. but its give duplication in months. I used distinct to remove duplication. now its works perfectly. thanks, bro. May God gives you health and wealth. Stay Bless.

Comment: Bro i have one more issue after grouping or sum when i select any row from lookupedit and on event QueryCloseUp its show other value null like StudentID, SessionID, ClassID other as well.

Comment: A GroupBy creates a two dimensional array : List<key(s),List<object>>  So to get the values you have to do like I did : VchNo = x.Last().VoucherN

Comment: It is working. But its causes duplication in Monts Column only. on for those students who paid their fees in this month of the previous year.

Comment: It only looks like duplication because you are not outputting the year.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
collection.GroupBy(x => x.StudentName).Select(g =>
  new{
    g.Last().VchNo,
    g.Last().StudentName,
    Month = string.Join(',', g.Select(gg => g.Month)),
    TotalAmount = g.Sum(gg => g.TotalAmount)
  }
);
```

I have guessed the property names because you didn't include them. Modify the code to substitute your actual entity names

Comment: g.Month and g.TotalAmount show the error "Does not contain a definition for Month and TotalAmount

Comment: You didn't specify what your client side property names were (but they sure can't contain spaces!) you just said what the database table looked like (your column names really contain spaces??). You'll have to change those to whatever your property names actually are. If you don't provide a complete info in a question, you usually have to accept that an answer might not work as a straight copy-paste; your effort is still required

Comment: thanks a lot. I have updated my question with code and two pictures. Now you can suggest me better query.